# BigQuery table creation from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a table in Google BigQuery Table in the console. I have given the correct GCS bucket address where the CSV resides. The CSV is about 140GB.
I have selected the Schema Auto detect option.

But when I click the CREATE TABLE button, I get the following error:

> Failed to create table: An internal error occurred and the request
> could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue.
> Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should
> solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error
> continues to occur please contact support at
> https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 9724253

What is the error over here and what changes should I do in the process of creating the table.

Comment: Is the error occurring with this file only?

Comment: yes.. I have tried earlier with small files.

Comment: Do you have tried by CLI too?

`bq load \
    --autodetect \
    --source_format=CSV \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.csv`

Comment: You could  first create the schema manually before uploading the csv file. Another option could be to create a small file of 1 GB from the 140GB file and try to upload.

Comment: I second the use of the bq command.  If it fails there, lets look at the GCP logs for errors.